# $\pi_2(G)$ for $G$ a Lie group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

It is well known that $\pi_2(G)$ is trivial for any Lie-group $G$. Is there an elementary proof of this, say, that can be understood with minimal homotopy theory?

Also, who gave the first proof of this theorem?

Comment: This was discussed on MathOverflow a while ago. Have you looked there?

Comment: Jason DeVito gives a lovely proof using Morse theory at [this MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups). The most homotopy theory used is the Hurewicz Theorem and the fibration of a pathspace with loopspace fibers.